# Picturebox collision with labels

Tags: vb.net

Okay so I have a picturebox which I have to check for collision against labels.
But since I have like 65 labels , is there a way to apply my statements to all labels at once instead of copying and pasting the if statement?

```
If PictureBox1.Bounds.IntersectsWith(Lbl1.Bounds) Then
    PictureBox1.Top = 84
    PictureBox1.Left = 18
    points()
End If

If PictureBox1.Bounds.IntersectsWith(Lbl2.Bounds) Then
    PictureBox1.Top = 84
    PictureBox1.Left = 18
    points()
End If

If PictureBox1.Bounds.IntersectsWith(Lbl3.Bounds) Then
    PictureBox1.Top = 84
    PictureBox1.Left = 18
    points()
End If
```

Comment: Check the form's .Controls property.

Comment: This code is very broken, it just gets a lot worse when you have to do it 65 times.  You have to throw it away.  Consider a UserControl so the relationship between the Label and the PictureBox is unambiguous.  A ListView with, say, View = Tile could work as well.